# how to collapse div to its height set in style property?

Tags: javascript, jquery

below is code for expand collapse div on hover. after multiple clicks on hyper links in div,or after multiple mouse hovers, sometimes div do not collapse to its display height when mouse is moved out.

is there any way to collapse div to its height set in style property of div on mouse out ?
my example page is :
http://apparelnbags.com:8000/showproduct2.aspx?ProductID=829
(Select different colors displayed in Active Colors block/div

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src='/jscripts/jquery-1.5/jquery-1.5.js'></script>

         <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function () {
                 var divHeight;
                 var contentHeight ;
                 $('.expand').hover(function () {
                     divHeight = $(this).height();
                     contentHeight = 0;
                     $(this).children().each(function () {
                         contentHeight += $(this).height();
                     });
                     if (divHeight < contentHeight) {
                         $(this).animate({
                             height: contentHeight
                         }, 300);
                     }
                 }, function () {
                     if (divHeight < contentHeight) {
                         $(this).animate({
                             height: divHeight
                         }, 300);
                     }
                 });
             });
        </script>
```

css for Div is

```
div.expand
{
    border: 1px solid #C8C8C8;overflow-y: scroll; -ms-overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Div Code is

```
<div class="text_theme_red_bold" style="Display:block;margin-top: 15px;width:438px">Active Colors:<br/>
    <div id="Color_Active"  class="expand"  style="Display:block;margin-top: 8px;padding:5px 0px 5px 5px;  height:36px;">
        (!Dynamic_Contents!)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried mouseenter / mouseleave ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: before each `$(this).animate(...)`, call `$(this).stop()` to end the previous animation.

Comment: dear sbonkosky, thanks for reply but still problem is there.. when mouse is speedly hovered on div, div does not collapses back..

just need to set div height to its height defined in css  when mouse is moved out of div?

Comment: dear aldux, how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this JS out:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var startHeight = $('.expand').height();
     var fullHeight = 0
     $('.expand').children().each(function () {
         fullHeight += $(this).height();
     });
     $('.expand').mouseenter(function(){
         $(this).stop();
         $(this).animate({
             height: fullHeight
         }, 320);
     });
     $('.expand').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).stop();
        $(this).animate({
            height:startHeight
        }, 320);         
     });
 });
```

Comment: thanks dear sbonkosky, but cannot maintain div initial height after multiple cliks and mouse hover. i think JQuery gets height property set by browser, and not the original height as set in css.